# Devtools not working when i try to inspect elements for selenium python it goes to previous page

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, devtools

so this was the site i was trying to inspect elements extract video source
https://uflix.to/episode/x-men-97-2024/S01E01
and after i open the element se4lecter after a lot of research i got to know this was the js used in this video player in this repo https://github.com/theajack/disable-devtool
is there any ways to bypass this also i need other streams too in that site there are 5 streams how to extract video src from all that such a weird site
plz explain in a very good manner all my before questions pplz were talking shit
thanks for understanding

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and ["How much research effort is expected?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck, you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. At a minimum you need to provide the relevant HTML, properly formatted, but additionally a link to the page is usually very helpful.